# Question about normal space exercise, help!

Tags: general-topology, continuity

**Question**:

> Given two distinct points $x_1$, $x_2$ of normal space $X$, show that
>   there exists continuous function $f:X\to\mathbb R$ such that $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$.

**My attempt:**

I thought last process of proof is using Urysohn's lemma, so I tried hard to take two closed sets $C$, $D$, which contains $x_1, x_2$. So long time I can't solved. Please help!

Comment: Have you tried $\{x_1\}$ and $\{x_2\}$?

Comment: I missed that simple idea... thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is good. Take $C=\{x_1\}$ and $D=\{x_2\}$, which are closed sets since, [by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_space#Definitions), every normal space is [$T_1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space).